# Overriding init method to allocate memory for instance variable object

Tags: objective-c, initialization, overriding, alloc, ivar

I am attempting to override the `init` method of a class so that initializing the object also initializes the ivar object:

```
-(id)init 
  {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
       someIVarObject = [SomeClass alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
  }
```

1) Would this code even work, and even so, is this solution discouraged?
2) Why is the `if` condition not `==` ?  Is it an assignment?  If so, why the `if`?

Sorry if this is obvious! >_<

Comment: Concerning your question 2) please take a look a this page : http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would work, and afaik it's still the way it should be done.

What it does is to call `[super init]` and allows it to do one of three things;

- Return self (ie the same object `self` is already set to.
- Return an entirely new object.
- Return `nil` for failure.

The result is then assigned to `self`, which makes sure that the rest of the constructor operates on the correct object in case it changed. The `if` is there to catch the case where `[super init]` returned nil, in which case the rest of the constructor should be skipped.

Comment: "afaik it's still the way it should be done" Providing you really do want an ivar. `@property`s are usually a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

1) Here you are declaring a local variable `someIVarObject`. You should have declared this within the interface or implementation of your class in curly braces, and should then assign it as `someIvarObject = ...`. An example:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    SomeClass *someIvarObject;
}

- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        someIvarObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

2) It is an assignment. There is a long history behind this idiom but it mostly comes down to handling the possibility that `[super init]` returns a different object than `init` was originally invoked upon.

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
if(self = [super init])
```

will work, but it will give you a compiler warning (unless you've turned off this warning).

You can also suppress the warning by using double parenthesis:

```
if((self = [super init]))
```

My current preference:

```
self = [super init];
if(self)
```

Comment: You current preference is very clean, like @AndreyChernukha 's suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You've got some typos, unbalanced brackets, and the thing you say is an ivar is not an ivar (you declare it inside the `if`, which makes its scope local to that block. You want to put instance variables in the `{}`s after your `@implementation` or `@interface` declarations). But yes, this is generally how this would work.

However, I'd take a hard look at whether you really need an ivar or not. I can't remember the last time I used one in my code. 99% of the situations I used to use them in, a `@property` is now a much better solution.

As an added benefit, `@property`s synthesize their own getters and setters, (usually) obviating the need to write manual `alloc`ing boilerplate, thus making this question moot.

Comment: sorry I realise this is an old comment but if you do see this can you explain what manual allocing boilerplate you would need when u don't use a property. Are u only referring to the setting, getting, etc. or something else re allocating?

Comment: It's been too long, I don't remember what I was talking about ;-) But I don't think you'd need any extra allocing boilerplate. What you'd need is to be extra-careful of retain/release semantics. An ivar is just a pointer. A property is a reference with known ownership semantics (strong, weak, copy, etc) that lets ARC (or the synthesized getter/setter in MRC) manage reference counts for you.

Comment: Cool - I guess you meant manually writing the setting and getting code when you don't use properties. Thanks for coming back to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

1) this code will work but this line:

```
SomeClass *someIVarObject = [SomeClass alloc] init];
```

makes a little sense. Declare `SomeClass *someIVarObject` in .h file and initialize it in init like this:

```
someIVarObject = [SomeClass alloc] init];
```

2) this line `if (self = [super init])` is equivalent to:

```
self = [super init]; if (self != nil)
```

i.e. it ensures that init method of the base class has returned a proper value